# Underscore.js 1.8.3 vs Underscore.js 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to adding values to template dynamically.

and when I use backbone render function with underscore _template() , it renders the model data only if I use Underscore 1.4.2 , but doesn't update the <%=name%> , if I use underscore 1.8.3.

```
This is my template:
<h2>Hiii, <%=name%> .</h2>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Considering underscores documentation uses an example almost exactly like your code, `var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");`, it's hard to see what might be wrong with it. I think you have to show more code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that template. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: You neglect to show us exactly how you're using `_.template`. I'd guess that you're hitting the ["Underscore templates no longer accept an initial `data` object. `_.template` always returns a function now."](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog) change from 1.7.0. With 1.4.2. you could say `html = _.template(tmpl, { ... })` but as of 1.7.0 you have to `t = _.template(tmpl); html = t({ ... })`.